Building Android Studio 2024.2.1 fails
I'm trying to build Android Studio 2024.2.1 from source according to the instructions here on Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64. When I run tools/idea/build_studio.sh, I get an error indicating that there's a bunch of missing plugins, and the instructions say nothing about this.
  events: exception (exception.escaped=true, exception.message=The following modules from productProperties.productLayout.bundledPluginModules aren't found in the project: [intellij.c.clangd.plugin, intellij.c.clangdBridge.plugin, intellij.c.plugin, intellij.cidr.debugger.plugin, intellij.cidr.base.plugin, intellij.cidr.clangConfig.plugin, intellij.cidr.clangFormat.plugin, intellij.rml.dfa.plugin], exception.stacktrace=
  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following modules from productProperties.productLayout.bundledPluginModules aren't found in the project: [intellij.c.clangd.plugin, intellij.c.clangdBridge.plugin, intellij.c.plugin, intellij.cidr.debugger.plugin, intellij.cidr.base.plugin, intellij.cidr.clangConfig.plugin, intellij.cidr.clangFormat.plugin, intellij.rml.dfa.plugin]
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildTasksImplKt.checkModules(BuildTasksImpl.kt:723)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildTasksImplKt.checkPluginModules(BuildTasksImpl.kt:747)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildTasksImplKt.checkProductLayout(BuildTasksImpl.kt:630)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildTasksImplKt.checkProductProperties(BuildTasksImpl.kt:558)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildTasksImplKt.access$checkProductProperties(BuildTasksImpl.kt:1)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildTasksImplKt$buildDistributions$$inlined$useWithScope$default$1.invokeSuspend(trace.kt:162)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildTasksImplKt$buildDistributions$$inlined$useWithScope$default$1.invoke(trace.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildTasksImplKt$buildDistributions$$inlined$useWithScope$default$1.invoke(trace.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:62)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:163)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildTasksImplKt.buildDistributions(BuildTasksImpl.kt:1232)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildTasksImpl.buildDistributions(BuildTasksImpl.kt:45)
    at AndroidStudioBuildTarget$main$1.invokeSuspend(AndroidStudioBuildTarget.kt:16)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:277)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:111)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$BuildersKt__BuildersKt(Builders.kt:84)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:52)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:48)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at AndroidStudioBuildTarget.main(AndroidStudioBuildTarget.kt:11)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.build.impl.BuildScriptLauncher.main(BuildScriptLauncher.kt:34)
  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘, exception.type=java.lang.IllegalStateException, time=15:14:20.2646)


The instructions for building with IntelliJ IDEA are out of date, so I can't exactly follow them, but nothing is said about plugin installation anyways.
